# QT: Complex Layout and seamless window background image

Tags: qt

With some help from you QT sages, I was able to implement this window, with the desired layout and resizeability behavior. Now I have another interesting problem.

I want my entire window to have a "repeat-xy" seamless pattern. If I apply it to a simple window without layout and internal widgets, it works perfectly. I do however, now have a "tree" of widgets within widgets, and I can't set the stylesheet to draw my seamless background image to each and every one, cause it looks unnatural. The image must be underlying to all the widget topology I have. The problem is, it's invisible when i apply it to the bottom all-window-covering widget because it has widgets on top of it.

Is there a solution? maybe "transparent widgets" that can contain visible widgets?

[image: My window]

Comment: I guess I am looking for a "div" kind of a solution, a container that doesn't draw itself and lets what's visual below it "shine through"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the following using only CSS, there's a QPlainTextEdit, two QPushButton and a QLineEdit. In the image i added a red border to the QPlainTextEdit only so it can be seen, the rules are the following

```
QWidget#Form{
    background-image: url(:/img/elephant_pattern.gif);
}
QPlainTextEdit{
    background:transparent;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

As you can see all i had to was setting background transparent in the widgets i wanted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Write your own widget that inherits QWidget. Reimplement the paintEvent and leave it empty. The widget itself won't be drawn, but its children will be.

```
my_widget::my_widget( QWidget* parent ) : QWidget( parent )
{
}

void my_widget::paintEvent( QPaintEvent* p_event )
{
    // left empty to let my_widget be invisible
}

test_mw::test_mw( QWidget *parent ) : QMainWindow( parent )
{
    test_widget = new my_widget( this );

    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout();

    QPushButton* button0 = new QPushButton( "Button 0", 0 );
    QPushButton* button1 = new QPushButton( "Button 1", 0 );

    layout->addWidget( button0 );
    layout->addWidget( widget );

    test_widget->setLayout( layout );

    setCentralWidget( test_widget );
}
```

[image]

Although the paintEvent of my_widget is empty, both QPushButtons are drawn. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There was a QWidget::setBackgroundOrigin() method in earlier versions of Qt.

It's all done with styles now. See the examples http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/widgets-styles.html